# Perl cron job stays running

Tags: perl, arduino, command-line-arguments, cron

I'm currently using a cron job to have a perl script that tells my arduino to cycle my aquaponics system and all is well, except the perl script doesn't `die` as intended.

Here is my cron job:

```
*/15 * * * * /home/dburke/scripts/hal/bin/main.pl cycle
```

And below is my perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Sample Perl script to transmit number
# to Arduino then listen for the Arduino
# to echo it back

use strict;
use Device::SerialPort;
use Switch;
use Time::HiRes qw ( alarm );
$|++;
# Set up the serial port
# 19200, 81N on the USB ftdi driver
my $device = '/dev/arduino0';
# Tomoc has to use a different tty for testing
#$device = '/dev/ttyS0';

my $port = new Device::SerialPort ($device)
    or die('Unable to open connection to device');;
$port->databits(8);
$port->baudrate(19200);
$port->parity("none");
$port->stopbits(1);

my $lastChoice = ' ';
my $signalOut;
my $args = shift(@ARGV);
# Parent must wait for child to exit before exiting itself on CTRL+C
if ($args eq "cycle") {
                open (LOG, '>>log.txt');
                print LOG "Cycle started.\n";
                my $stop = 0;
                sleep(2);
                $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
                        print "Expecting plant bed to be full; please check.\n";
                        $signalOut = $port->write('2'); # Signal to set pin 3 low
                        print "Sent cmd: 2\n";
                        $stop = 1;
                };
                $signalOut = $port->write('1'); # Signal to arduino to set pin 3 High
                print "Sent cmd: 1\n";
                print "Waiting for plant bed to fill...\n";
                print LOG "Alarm is being set.\n";
                alarm (420);
                print LOG "Alarm is set.\n";
                while ($stop == 0) {
                        print LOG "In while-sleep loop.\n";
                        sleep(2);
                }
                print LOG "The loop has been escaped.\n";
                die "Done.";
                print LOG "No one should ever see this.";
    }
    else {
        my $pid = fork();
        $SIG{'INT'} = sub {
            waitpid($pid,0) if $pid != 0; exit(0);
        };

        # What child process should do
        if($pid == 0) {
            # Poll to see if any data is coming in
            print "\nListening...\n\n";
            while (1) {
                my $incmsg = $port->lookfor(9);
                # If we get data, then print it
                if ($incmsg) {
                    print "\nFrom arduino: " . $incmsg . "\n\n";
                }
            }
        }
        # What parent process should do
        else {
                    sleep(1);
                    my $choice = ' ';
                    print "Please pick an option you'd like to use:\n";
                    while(1) {
                        print " [1] Cycle  [2] Relay OFF  [3] Relay ON  [4] Config  [$lastChoice]: ";
                        chomp($choice = <STDIN>);
                        switch ($choice) {
                                case /1/ {
                                        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {
                                                        print "Expecting plant bed to be full; please check.\n";
                                                        $signalOut = $port->write('2'); # Signal to set pin 3 low
                                                        print "Sent cmd: 2\n";
                                                        };
                                        $signalOut = $port->write('1'); # Signal to arduino to set pin 3 High
                                        print "Sent cmd: 1\n";
                                        print "Waiting for plant bed to fill...\n";
                                        alarm (420);
                                        $lastChoice = $choice;
                                }
                                case /2/ {
                                        $signalOut = $port->write('2'); # Signal to set pin 3 low       
                                        print "Sent cmd: 2";
                                        $lastChoice = $choice;
                                }
                                case /3/ {
                                        $signalOut = $port->write('1'); # Signal to arduino to set pin 3 High
                                        print "Sent cmd: 1";
                                        $lastChoice = $choice;
                                }
                                case /4/ {
                                        print "There is no configuration available yet. Please stab the developer.";
                                }
                            else        { print "Please select a valid option.\n\n";}
                        }
                   }
           }
}
```

When I run `ps -ef` I find the following output:

```
dburke   15294 15293  0 14:30 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c /home/dburke/scripts/hal/bin/main.pl cycle
dburke   15295 15294  0 14:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/perl -w /home/dburke/scripts/hal/bin/main.pl cycle
```

Shouldn't there only be one process?  Is it forking even though it received the cycle argument and the fork is outside of the cycle argument's `if` block?

Any idea why it wouldn't die from the statement `die "Done.";`?  It runs fine from the command line and interprets the 'cycle' argument fine.  When it runs in cron it runs fine, however, the process never dies and while each process doesn't continue to cycle the system it does seem to be looping in some way due to the fact that it ups my system load very quickly.

If you'd like more information, just ask.  Thanks guys!

Comment: Does it do this when you run the command from the command line or is it specifically a cron problem?

Comment: Is it blocked somewhere, or is it endlessly looping?

Comment: I updated my question; sorry for the ambiguity guys. :)

Comment: I wasn't looking for a yes/no answer. Keep digging... What's the last thing it executed? Or what statements is it looping over? ...And should find that out for both the parent and the child.

Comment: How do I check what it's looping or what the last thing that was executed was?

Comment: The only way I know it's still running is by using `ps -ef` and just seeing the processes.

Comment: In `syslog` the following message is printed when it runs from cron:
`Sep 27 19:15:01 Mckay CRON[12659]: (dburke) CMD (/home/dburke/scripts/hal/bin/main.pl cycle)`

Comment: Try tracing it to see what it's doing.

Comment: Add statements that print progress through the script. (Sorry, didn't know you replied since I wasn't tagged @ikegami)

Comment: The documentation for `alarm` says that you should not mix calls to it with `sleep`, and vice-versa, because `sleep` and `alarm` may clobber each other's timer.  My first thought when reading your code was that this is the likely cause of your problem; however, I couldn't generate such a problem with a simple test program, and it also wouldn't explain a difference in behavior when run from cron.  Still, it might be worth a look. How about rewriting your sleep loop to simply have a maximum iteration count, instead of using alarm() and a signal handler?

Comment: You could try manually sending a SIGALRM to the process and see what happens: kill -14 <pid>

Comment: I attempted to use ptrace, but it was a little out of my skill range for now.  I've setup prints to a log file that hopefully will help me, but when I run using `./main.pl cycle` it cycles fine, but doesn't produce output in the log file.  Does anyone see anything immediately wrong with how I set that up?

Comment: Oops.  I'm not patient enough or something.  It printed to the log file, but not until the end of the script...

I have since added a `close(LOG)` statement as well.  I'm not sure why it would matter, but I figured it was proper to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as thought the issue was that my script originally encapsulated the `cycle` block inside of the `fork` which for some reason, unknown to me, was leaving a process open (possibly the child?).  Taking the `cycle` block out of the fork has corrected the issue.  Now it runs at the specified time and correctly dies after the cycle is complete leaving my cpu load for something more useful. :)

**Thank you everyone who commented on my question. You suggestions helped me work through the issue.**